# PochDB sync when already exist

Tags: react-native, pouchdb

I'm fresh new with PoucDB and couldn't figure it out from the docs nor the web.
I have a local pouchDb which is synced live with a remote couchDB.
I have to wait until sync is completed before logging user in.
Because sync can take several minutes, I would like to only get changed data in the next time app is started, instead of syncing and waiting again.
I'm sure it's possible, but can't find how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to only get changed data in the next time app is started

According to my experience, that's the default behavior of PouchDB. PouchDB keeps the local database, and only pushes/pulls changes to/from remote database.

> I have to wait until sync is completed before logging user in

I'm not sure what you mean. The way I use PouchDB might be different. Firstly I make sure that the user is authenticated by the [pouchdb-authentication](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication#dbloginusername-password--options--callback), secondly, if user is authenticated, then I start syncing local and remote PouchDB databases. At this point, as I told before, local PouchDB database only pushes/pulls `changes` to/from remote database.